# In mongoose, is model.save atomic for increment or should I always use $inc?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, atomic

I need to increment the likes field of a record in MongoDB and mongoose, but I'm little 'worried' about atomicity of these operations, as this should be concurrently-safe:

```
Post.findById(id, function(err, post) {
  post.update({$inc: {
      likes: 1
  }});
});
```

vs

```
Post.findById(id, function(err, post) {
    post.likes++;
    post.save()
});
```

Do they provide the same secure result? Think about the fact that I have even to decrement the likes of the record (e.g. if the user clicks again on the like button)

```
Post.findById(id, function(err, post) {
  post.update({$inc: {
      likes: -1
  }});
});
```

Comment: In the second case operation is not atomic, because until model is saving, there is can be send another request and the loaded `likes` will have the previous value.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I thought. If you want to transform the comment into an answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB `$inc` is an atomic operation within a single document (see [mongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#behavior)).

In the second case, the operation is not atomic, because when the model is saving, another request could be sent, and the loaded `likes` will have the previous value.

Comment: Technically, it's still atomic. Just not accurate.

Comment: `Post.findById` and `post.update` are both async functions, you absolutely don't know when they will be finished, and how many other calls will be processed during this time.

Comment: Yes they're async (as with most io operations in Node), but I'm not sure you're mental model of an 'atomic' operation is correct. It means that it either succeeds or fails, no 'in between' state if for some reason the operation is interrupted.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/

Comment: @mrBorna the find/save sequence is not atomic. Just the save by itself and just the find by itself are.